# Unable to hide/show div

Tags: jquery

I need to hide one div and show one div. 
I am new to Jquery but I've tried several methods that i could find. It still doesn't work and i have no idea. 
Anyone has any idea? Very much appreciated for your help.

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Claim" OnClientClick="cfrm();"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" runat="server" visible="false">

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function cfrm() {
                var fee = $('[id$=lblTotalProcedureFee]').text();
                if (fee > 500) {
                    if (confirm('You are making a claim exceeding $500. Are you sure to do this operation?')) {
                        $('#div1').hide('fast');
                        $('#div2').show();
                    }
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: whta have you tried? Show some code!!

Comment: Is there any reason `hide()` and `show()` don't work for you?

Comment: You really need to include more information if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: A few friendly pointers: First, when you have problem with code, *show the code*, or a brief example that easily reproduces your problem. Second, "doesn't work" isn't an adequate problem description. You need to be more clear. Imagine we have *no idea* what you're doing.

Comment: sorry took me a while to edit codes

Comment: In general, check your console for error messages before posting a question (and include message if relevant). I'm sure you get an error saying `show` is undefined, because you use it as a variable here.

Comment: Much better question now, removing downvote :)

Comment: What is the behavior that you are currently seeing? Where does it fail? Does the `confirm` prompt appear? Check your JS console to see if there are any error messages. Is jQuery correctly included (does it work anywhere else in the page)? Also, in general, if you show the rendered HTML rather than the aspx markup we are more likely to be able to [easily reproduce the problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: hi @nbrooks .. the function is correct and the confirm message was shown. i didn't get any error message. the div1 didn't disappear and div2 didn't appear.. that's all i can tell..

Comment: That's strange, with the typo fixed it should work. Can you reproduce the error on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: is that because i'm using master page which has updatepanel in it?

now that i added the following code,
$("div").off();
$('[id$=div1]').off();
$('[id$=div1]').hide();
$('[id$=div2]').show();

div 1 disappeared.. but reappeared again and div2 didn't appear at all..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You have to initially hide the other div

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to hide

Answer (score 0):

For your specific code...your last line should invoke jQuery's [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show) method

```
function cfrm() {
    //...
            $('#div1').hide('fast');
            $('#div2').show();
}
```

---

In general, you can use jQuery [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) to alternate visibility between two items

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div id='d1' class='alternate'>Blah1</div>
<div id='d2' class='alternate hidden'>Blah2</div>
<button id='hideBtn'>Hide/Show</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#hideBtn').click( function() {
        $('.alternate').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery library File

[Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/u6fn6/3/)

HTML

```
<span class="tab">Click Here to See / Hide Hidden Output</span>
<div class="output">This is our Hidden output</div>
```

CSS

```
.output{  display:none;  }
.tab{ bordar:1px solid;   background:#d0d0d0; cursor:pointer; padding:5px; }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').click(function(){
      $('.output').toggle();
    });
});
```